# WordPress Plugin If / Then Condition

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am working on a plugin for my website. It works well enough, except, I want it to display something on condition of whether the value is empty or not.

The relevant piece of the plugin.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: MyDateTest
 * ...
 */
add_filter("the_content", "add_custom_date");

function add_custom_date($content)
{
    if (is_singular("page") {
        return $content;
    } else {
        $post = get_post();
        $content =
            "<br/><strong>Date:</strong> " .
            get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "custom_month", true) .
            "/" .
            get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "custom_day", true) .
            "/" .
            get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "custom_year", true) .
            $content;
        return $content;
    }
}

?>
```

If there is a value in each of the custom fields of month, day, and year. The output will correctly display as:
`1/1/1980`.
If there is a missing month or day:
`1//1980` or `/1/1980`.

I have seen this code
`if( empty( $price_list) ) : ?>style="display:none"<?php endif; ?>` from a stackexchange question, but I have inserted variations of that in so many places of my code and cannot get it to work.

I cannot figure out the appropriate location or configuration, any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: _"each of the custom fields of month, day, and year"_ - why are you storing a date(?) value in three separate fields in the first place?